# NTFS Repair - chkdsk from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, live-usb, ntfs

How can I run Window's **chkdsk.exe** from my *Linux USB Rescue Stick* to fix an NTFS drive?

This is for a media player. I'm long done with Windows, but am forced to hold an installation available on my netbook to fix this disk now and then! I want to get rid of this otherwise useless partition.

The Linux tool, ntfsfix from ntfs-3g, is no replacement for Windows chkdsk!

Comment: I see that you have a solution to share, which is fine, but the answer you've given does not answer "run chkdsk.exe from my USB stick to fix an NTFS drive". It shows how to create a particular USB stick.

Comment: Boot the *Mini Windows Xp*, open a *Command prompt* and  run `chkdsk.exe NTFS_DRIVE: /F /V`

Comment: What you've created in your answer  is not a "Linux Rescue USB stick". It's using Linux to create some sort of *Windows* recovery disk that can run a Windows-based chkdsk on a Windows partition. The only on-topic part of this IMHO is the Linux steps to create the device. Please edit your question to focus on that.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but my intentions should have become clear.

Comment: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the MiniXP on [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/). The included version 5.1.2600.0 is a little outdated but does the job.

With this I'm able to obtain the full functionality of chkdsk.exe with merely another boot entry on my rescue stick!

Here is my manual, step-by-step, linux-only approach with an *emtpy* usb stick:

start a **bash** session in a terminal

```
mkdir /tmp/d1 && cd /tmp/d1

wget http://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip

unzip Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip

mkdir iso

sudo mount -o loop,ro,uid=$UID Hiren\'s.BootCD.15.2.iso iso
```

plug in the usb stick you want to use: **careful**! everything on it    will be deleted!

determine the device of the stick:

```
dmesg
```

or

```
journalctl
```

or

```
less /var/log/syslog
```

note device and partition:

```
USB_STICK=  # e.g. /dev/sdb

USB_STICK_PARTITION=${USB_STICK}1
```

recheck it:

```
/sbin/fdisk -l $USB_STICK
```

check if mounted:

```
mount | grep $USB_STICK
```

if yes: unmount device or partition(s)

```
sudo umount ${USB_STICK}{,{1..4}}
```

clear it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$USB_STICK count=10000
```

download syslinux:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-6.03.tar.gz
```

extract it:

```
tar xzf syslinux-6.03.tar.gz
```

write master boot record:

```
sudo dd if=syslinux-6.03/bios/mbr/mbr.bin of=$USB_STICK
```

create a FAT32 partition, e.g.

```
echo ,,c,\* | sudo sfdisk $USB_STICK
```

format it:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -n MINIXP -v $USB_STICK_PARTITION
```

make it bootable:

```
sudo syslinux-6.03/bios/linux/syslinux --install $USB_STICK_PARTITION
```

copy content:

```
mkdir usb

sudo mount -o uid=$UID $USB_STICK_PARTITION usb

cp -rv iso/* usb
```

create config file:

```
echo "default minixp\nlabel minixp\nboot /HBCD/grldr" >usb/syslinux.cfg
```

make **MiniXP** default:

```
sed -i '/^default/s|/default|2|' usb/HBCD/menu.lst
```

tidy up:

```
sudo umount $USB_STICK_PARTITION

sudo umount iso

cd ..
rm -r d1
```

done!

I deleted Parted Magic and the big virus stuff and got it down to *200MB* on my Rescue Stick.

Adjust this procedure appropriate for your own rescue stick!

Comment: **Hiren's boot CD is a pirated copy of Windows with additional pirated shareware tools** and a bunch of freeware as well.

Comment: Who cares? For years I was a Windows Hacker too. (In remembrance of **SoftICE**...)

Comment: Piracy is not admitted on this site. You are free to be a criminal elsewhere given there are plenty of legal ways to create a bootable Windows disk.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto actually, there are no such rules on SE. In fact, [the rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8492/203101) is kind of the opposite: enforcing laws is not our job, nor are we qualified to do it. Nor can we know the legality of actions in the jurisdiction of each user (also see [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127892/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80495/)). In any case, this post isn't advocating piracy! You can perhaps argue that the tool mentioned is breaking licences, but the use it is being put to in this answer is legitimate.

Comment: @terdon, it has already be discussed several times. I guess you remember why nobody can ask about installing OS X on non Apple hardware here on SE. Those questions get pruned immediately. Also, this answer does not answer the question as it never mentions chkdsk. Finally, the user's attitude of "who cares" regarding to piracy is both baffling and offending beyond every kind of "be nice" policy that I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto the policy you mention is specific to [su] and something they decided on their meta, not an SE-wide decision. I am very simply not qualified to judge whether Hiran's boot CD is illegal so cannot opine on that. The answer would indeed benefit from a mention of `chckdisk`, yes, but that is another issue. Presumably, you can run it from the USB created. As for the attitude, again, that's not relevant to the technical aspects of the answer. The general stance on possibly illegal activities has indeed been discussed and the consensus is: we cannot enforce laws.

Comment: @terdon I agree we cannot really *enforce* them, but trying not to *promote* breaking them seems feasible IMHO. Interesting that the policy I cited is considered specific to Super User. As far as I remember they based it entirely on the SE terms of use. But OK, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Update from more recent times - the HBCD website linked is now a different set of owners and is based on Windows PE rather than a full version of Windows. The legality is a little more complex on that front now as each of the included utilities and Windows software, along with the Windows binaries would need their licences checking.

Comment: The links to HBCD 15.2 and syslinux 6.03 still working, so this hack should too.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you consider running `chkdsk.exe` under [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) or virtualisation, Linux cannot run it. There is a linux compatible tool that can be used to fix ntfs partitions that is called `ntfsfix` and is available on most distribution repositories.

It is NOT chkdsk for Linux and may not produce results compatible with Microsoft Windows, however it is able to fix **some** common ntfs possible problems. It **may lose your data while attempting repairs**, even though chkdsk may do that too. Example usage:

```
ntfsfix /dev/sdxY
```

Where you should replace `xY` with the appropriate letters for the partition you want to fix.

Comment: Truism! That's why I asked explicitly for *chkdsk.exe*.